# What should I implement for a small popup control in a VSTO project?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, vsto, office-addins

In my VSTO projects (Office 2007 / 2010) I would like to use a small popup control (think Tooltip like features; fade animation and mouse interaction).

I would prefer to use WPF.  If I were to do this in WPF I would create a custom Popup Control.

In VSTO, as far as I understand it, I must use a WPF window and then have 2 options, either I put this window in a Windows Form Container or I get the Hwnd of my office app and I add this Hwnd to the Owner property of a WPF Window.  Am I correct here?

Creating a whole window, animating it on and off the screen etc to look like a ToolTip seems to be overkill.

So my question is how should I do this.  I would prefer WPF.

I don't know if this would work but my first thought is to build a very tiny WPF window which is transparent and start it with the Office App.  I can then build a Popup Control (which is a child of this tiny window) which I show and not show at a mouse position.  Pretty sure a popup can appear outside the bounds of its parent window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to tidy up my own question with what I did.  In the VSTO addin project I added a reference to WindowsBase, PresentationFramework and presentation core.

And then I just follow any tutorial or example that adds a WPF Popup. By popup I mean a System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.  For the Placement I used PlacementMode.Absolute and then used a window point to set its position.

This pretty much answers my question.  Of course this popup is literally floating above your office window so you will need to make sure that you control it for example if the office window moves, is minimized and the like.